# How do I write a regex that includes all values from 1801-1899 (including 1801 and 1899)?

Tags: regex

How do I write a regex that includes all values from 1801-1899 (including 1801 and 1899)?

This is for use in Blackboard (which I think uses html).  I am not a programmer.  I am trying to have it grade as correct all answers that fall in this range.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You say you're not a programmer, but you seem to be asking us about your solution not the problem you're trying to solve.  You might get a better answer if you explain *what* you want to do instead of asking *how* you should implement your chosen solution.

Comment: My apologies: I am writing a quiz question on Blackboard and I am new to their testing format.  For one of my questions (e.g., "Write a date that would fall within the 19th century" - this is not the question, but the general idea), I want Blackboard to accept a specific range of 4-digit responses - in this case, only the values between 1801-1899.

Comment: I'm going to add ^ (beginning string) and $ (ending string) so the answer I provided below matches a string containing _only_ 1801-1899.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - that worked nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Since 1800 is the only exception, you might want to consider something like this:

```
^\w*18(?:[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9])\w*$
```

This will match 1801 to 1899.  It ignores whitespace at the beginning or the end, and otherwise won't match anything else because the string must start immediately before and end immediately after the (optional) whitespace.

https://regex101.com/r/O442aO/3/

Comment: () is group match, so although this would work it would generate groups.  If you just want a match I think you'd want: `18(?:[1-9][0-9]|0[1-9])`

Comment: Thank you all for your help - it is very appreciated